# Influence of #pragma pack on outer struct?

Tags: c, struct, c-preprocessor, pragma-pack

#### Problem

I stumbled over alignment issues when accessing a member of a struct (on ARMv7). The accessed member itself is also a struct but packed with the infamous `#pragma pack(1)` preprocessor directive. The outer struct is not packed so a naive developer like me would suspect that the address of the member is aligned according to the alignment settings of the outer struct. But obviously this is not the case: The static assertion which checks the alignment of this member fails. When removing the `#pragma pack` (or when aligning the member via GCC attributes) the alignment is as suspected.

#### Question(s)

Why does the packing of the inner struct affect the alignment of members of the outer struct? What is the preferred method for aligning this member?

#### Example Code

*Note:* In this example the usage of the `pragma pack` directive is pretty obvious. In the real world the struct is declared in a header of an external library which is somewhat out of sight.

```
#include "stdint.h"
#include "stddef.h"
#include "stdbool.h"

#pragma pack(1)
struct a
{
    uint32_t one;
    uint32_t two;
};
#pragma pack()

struct b
{
    uint32_t foo;
    bool bar;
    struct a foobar;// __attribute__((aligned(sizeof(void *))));
};

_Static_assert((offsetof(struct b, foobar) % 4 == 0),
               "alignment issue");
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:23,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:23,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:23,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:23,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%22stdint.h%22%0A%23include+%22stddef.h%22%0A%23include+%22stdbool.h%22%0A%0A%23pragma+pack(1)%0Astruct+a%0A%7B%0A++++uint32_t+one%3B%0A++++uint32_t+two%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%23pragma+pack()%0A%0Astruct+b%0A%7B%0A++++uint32_t+foo%3B%0A++++bool+bar%3B%0A++++struct+a+foobar%3B//+__attribute__((aligned(sizeof(void+*))))%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A_Static_assert((offsetof(struct+b,+foobar)+%25+4+%3D%3D+0),%0A+++++++++++++++%22alignment+issue%22)%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.54249866558628,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:carmhfg54,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27ARM+gcc+5.4+(linux)+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:28.124168001080392,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+ARM+gcc+5.4+(linux)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: I can just assume that the pragma marks the `struct a` as a type with alignment 1. At least I get the same assertion error if I change the type of `foobar` from `struct a` to `char`.

Comment: The inner struct doesn't affect the alignment of members of the outer struct. You can demonstrate this by adding a `uint32_t` member *after* `foobar` and then print the offsets of all four members. You'll see that the member after `foobar` is properly aligned. The issue is that `struct a` doesn't have any alignment restrictions because you packed it, so it can be placed anywhere in `struct b` without any padding. If you want `struct a` aligned in `struct b`, then applying an `__attribute__` seems like a reasonable approach.